# How to append output of each cursor iteration together using T-SQL (Html report designing)

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I am trying to generate a HTML report for monitoring using T-SQL.

I am not a developer/programmer but started to learn T-SQL. I am using a cursor to check and validate a result using case statement. Since I am trying to get the output in html format each cursor iteration should be appended to the previous one. I tried the code below and Commented html part for the testing purpose.

```
DECLARE @TableHTML1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dbname_bhtrs VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @bhtrs VARCHAR(50) -- database name  

PRINT @TableHTML1
SET @TableHTML1 = ''

PRINT @TableHTML1
PRINT 'here it should display set value'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  b.dbname, b.backup_Age_hours 
    FROM #backustatus b

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname_bhtrs, @bhtrs   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    SELECT
        @TableHTML1 = '<tr><td><font face="Verdana" size="2">' + 
                      ISNULL(@dbname_bhtrs, '') + '</font></td>' +
                      CASE
                         WHEN @bhtrs > 24 
                            THEN '</font></td>' +'<td><font face="Verdana" size="2">' +ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @bhtrs), '') +'</font></td></tr>' 
                         WHEN @bhtrs < 24 
                            THEN '</font></td>' +'<td><font face="Verdana" size="5">' +ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @bhtrs), '') +'</font></td></tr>'  
                      END
                  FROM
                      #backustatus b

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname_bhtrs,@bhtrs   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code? Add sample data and expected result

Comment: `@TableHTML1 += ...` or `@TableHTML1 = @TableHTML1 + ...` in your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

- `@TableHTML1` variable is reset in each loop. you have to add values to it. you can also use a simple select query to achieve your work. (It is **NOT recommended** to use *CURSORS* when your work can be achieved with a *SELECT* query)
- You are duplicating `'</font></td>'` value twice

  ```
  Declare @TableHTML1  VARCHAR(MAX)

  Print @TableHTML1
  set @TableHTML1 = ''


  SELECT @TableHTML1 = TableHTML1 +
         '<tr><td><font face="Verdana" size="2">' + 
         ISNULL(dbname, '') + '</font></td>' +
         case 
             when backup_Age_hours > 24 then '<td><font face="Verdana" size="2">' +ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), backup_Age_hours), '') +'</font></td></tr>' 
             when backup_Age_hours < 24 then '<td><font face="Verdana" size="5">' +ISNULL(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), backup_Age_hours), '') +'</font></td></tr>'  
             End 
  FROM #backustatus

  SELECT @TableHTML1
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works..i removed cursor from the script and tried it with your suggestion (Select).

Comment: @Nathan If this answer solved your problem [mark this answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).